Issues with Routing in React App Deployed on cPanel
I’m having trouble with client-side routing in my React application after deploying it to cPanel. The pages only load correctly after a manual refresh. Here’s a summary of my setup:
.htaccess file dataa
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>

.index.js file
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import { HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import Spinner from "./views/Spinner/Spinner";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
      <HashRouter>
        <App />
      </HashRouter>
    </Suspense>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();

router file
import React, { lazy } from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import FullLayout from "./layouts/FullLayout";
import Dashboard1 from "./views/Dashboard1";
import BasicTable from "./views/BasicTable";

const Login = lazy(() => import("../components/Login.js"));

/***** Routes *****/
const ThemeRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: <Login />,
  },
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <FullLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: "/", element: <Navigate to="dashboards/dashboard1" /> },
      { path: "dashboards/dashboard1", element: <Dashboard1 /> },
      { path: "tables/basic-table", element: <BasicTable /> },
    ]
  }
];

export default ThemeRoutes;







After deploying my React app to cPanel, the pages only load correctly if I manually refresh the page. What could be the cause of this issue?
I have already tried modifying the .htaccess file but it hasn’t resolved the problem. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
